# kafka stream with custom AVRO Serde (without schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro, hive-serde

I have a stream processing application using AVRO message format. For serialization and deserialization (Serde) it is using **io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde**.

I was trying to create custom AVRO Serde as something like below

```
public class CustomAvroSerde implements Serde<SpecificRecord> {

    Class<SpecificRecord> targetType;

    public CustomAvroSerde() {
         
    }

    public CustomAvroSerde(Class<SpecificRecord> targetType) {
        this.targetType = targetType;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializer<SpecificRecord> serializer() {
        return new Serializer<SpecificRecord>() {
            @Override
            public byte[] serialize(String s, SpecificRecord data) {
                byte[] result = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder =
                            EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(byteArrayOutputStream, null);

                    DatumWriter<SpecificRecord> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(data.getSchema());

                    try {
                        datumWriter.write(data, binaryEncoder);
                        binaryEncoder.flush();
                        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioException) {
                        ioException.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<SpecificRecord> deserializer() {
        return new Deserializer<SpecificRecord>() {
            @Override
            public SpecificRecord deserialize(String s, byte[] data) {
                SpecificRecord result = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    DatumReader<SpecificRecord> datumReader;
                    try {
                        BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = new DecoderFactory().createBinaryDecoder(data, null);
                        datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>()
                        //also tried with supplying schema as below commented line
                        //datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(new Schema.Parser().parse("avro schema in string form"));
                        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, binaryDecoder);
                        result = datumReader.read(null, decoder);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The process of serialization is working good, but while performing deserialization throwing Nullpointer, as the serde is not having reference of AVRO schema in targetType during de-serialization.

I will not be having schema details until runtime, hence looking for a generalized schema to be provided at deserialization.

Confluent Serde is initializing the targetType with KafkaAvroDeserializer. How to handle is this case. Any clue?

**Edited content**
Changed serialization and deserialization to use SpecificRecord.
After the code change, it was giving Nullpointer exception as given below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.applyAliases(Schema.java:1787)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.getResolver(GenericDatumReader.java:130)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
        at com.hcl.test.CustomAvroSerde$2.deserialize(CustomAvroSerde.java:74)
        at com.hcl.test.CustomAvroSerde$2.deserialize(CustomAvroSerde.java:56)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:63)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
```

As commented in the code, tried with Schema by passing it to SpecificDatumReader while constructing. When tried that, it was giving Casting exception as below,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord
    at com.hcl.test.CustomAvroSerde$2.deserialize(CustomAvroSerde.java:74)
    at com.hcl.test.CustomAvroSerde$2.deserialize(CustomAvroSerde.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:63)
```

Also enabled **specific.avro.reader** flag to **true**. 
**End of Edited content**

Thanks
Venkata

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the way Serde is implemented by confluent API (io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde), which i am using in my code, mandates schema registry. If i want to run the same code base on Apache Kafka, it requires custom Serde to by-pass schema validation with Schema Registry.

Comment: Apache Kafka comes with Confluent Platform. It doesn't care if you have Avro data, as long as it becomes bytes. That being said, yes, the Schema Registry serializers require the Registry URL to be configured. I don't understand your specific problem of needing to define your own Serde when Confluent already provides it. In order words, "targetType" is not needed, and if you really wanted this, you should be using a SpecificRecord subclass, not GenericRecord... Again, please show your NPE stacktrace in the question

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, edited the query with 2 of the scenarios tried with SpecificRecord. Pls find the updated query.

Comment: Are you using the Schema Registry, or not? Why do you want by "bypass schema validation"? You can set the compatibility level of the subject to NONE to do that on the server side, and therefore won't require your own Serde

Comment: Want to by-pass schema registry. Assume that, want to use plain vanilla kafka and want to have my own implementation of Serde.

Comment: As mentioned previously, there is no difference between "vanilla Kafka" and any vendor supplied version of it. The Schema Registry is an addon that works with any Kafka installation and if you do end up using or "wrapping" `io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes` classes, then you **are required** to use the Confluent Schema Registry, and thus cannot bypass, and really don't need to [re-write their source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java#L129-L149)